# Why does this code sample copy before returning?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking at a code sample for deserializing a JSON response. The last line `return [topics copy];` copies the array before returning. I've looked up the reason for this and it's to return an immutable NSArray.

However, is this standard practice or highly defensive programming? The calling method will assign the return value to something, and if it wants to assign the return value to an immutable `NSArray` it will do it. If it assigns the return value to an `NSMutableArray` then it will do that.

So my question is - is there any realistic scenario where this will prevent unwanted consequences?

```
// Returns array of @c NPTopic objects
- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response data:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    if (![self validateResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response data:data error:error]) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [super responseObjectForResponse:response data:data error:error];
    if (!JSONDictionary) return nil;

    // Note: the expected JSON format of this response is { data: [ { <a topic> }, { <another topic>} ], metadata: { ...} }
    NSArray *JSONTopics = JSONDictionary[@"data"];

    NSMutableArray *topics = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *JSONTopic in JSONTopics) {
        // For each topic in JSON format, we can deserialize it from JSON to our desired model class using Mantle
        NPTopic *topic = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[NPTopic class] fromJSONDictionary:JSONTopic error:error];
        if (!topic) return nil;
        [topics addObject:topic];
    }

    *error = nil;
    return [topics copy];
}
```

Comment: **Side note**: In case you're not running in an ARC environment, you should change the last line to use `[[topics copy] autorelease]`.

Answer (score 1):

The copy is so it returns an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableAray`. The issue is that if an `NSMutableAray` is returned it can be changed, that can be a problem is there are multiple pointers to it and one makes changes but another assumes that it is immutable and won't change.

It is good practice.

Don't make assumptions about the actual implementation, there are several ways that the "copy" can occur without actually making a copy. Being concerned about performance without a need and proof is called" Premature Optimization" and warned again by many including famously by Donald Knuth.

It really should have it's return typed `NSArray *`, not `id` so the compiler can catch type errors.

Comment: Gotcha. But let's say it did pass back the `NSMutableArray`. My question is, since the calling method will be assigning this return value to something immediately upon return, doesn't that mean that there is no scenario where  an NSMutableArray will be used when it isn't supposed to be used? I mean, I guess if the calling method assigns the return value to type `id`, then an NSMutableArray can still exist when it might not be desired.

Comment: If it passed back an `NSMutableArray`, it would just use `return topics`. An alternate would be `return [topics mutableCopy]`.

Comment: The calling method just assigns the pointer, the object does not change. The caller might pass the pointer on to another method so they both point to the mutable array.

Comment: Personal preference, to indicate that an immutable copy is being returned, I'd prefer to see `[NSArray arrayWithArray:topics]` as it takes research to indicate that `copy` returns an immutable array, whereas it's obvious that `arrayWithArray` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to @Zaph, let's try for an explanation...

Fundamental to Objective-C, and many other languages, is the concept of subclasses; an instance of class `B` which derives from a class `A` can *usually* be used whenever an instance of class `A` is required.

Because of this there is a lot of *type information loss*; pass an instance of `B` to something expecting an `A` then the receiver doesn't know unless it chooses to query the actual type - the receiver has less *information* about the instance's actual type, seing it as an `A`, while the actual instance still is a `B`.

The extreme case of type information loss is when an instance is stored in a container, such as `NSArray`, which justs stores "objects" (`id` or `NSArray *`) - when that instance is later extracted little is known about it *for certain*, though if the programmer has only stored, say, `NSString` instances then they can safely *assume* only `NSString` instances are extracted.

All this *usually* works fine.

Where the "usually" breaks down is when some fundamental property, such as mutability, changes in the derived class.

Consider the simple class (please no sexism etc. comments!):

```
@interface Woman : Person

@property NSString *maidenName;
@property NSString *marriedName;

@end

@implementation Woman
// nothing to do
@end
```

and the code fragment:

```
Woman *mary = [Woman new];

NSMutableString *name = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Mary Jones"];
mary.maidenName = name;

[name replaceOccurencesOfString:@"Jones" with:@"Williams];
mary.marriedName = name;
```

What is the value of `mary.maidenName`? *Mary Williams*... Probably not what was intended.

What might be the result if rather can create your own string as above you obtained it from a method which claimed to return an immutable string and you assigned it to `maidenName` or `marriedName`, but in fact the return string was mutable and subsequently changed elsewhere? Poor Mary would find her name changing.

To address this problem two rules are generally advised:

*Consumer:* If you are storing a reference to an object of an immutable class which has a mutable subclass then *copy* the object before storing to avoid surprises if the instance is in fact mutable. For the above example this can be done by adding the `copy` attribute to the properties:

```
@property (copy) NSString *maidenName;
@property (copy) NSString *marriedName;
```

*Producer:* If you are creating and returning an object instance which you declare is immutable, but during creation you use a mutable subclass, then make an immutable copy and return that. I.e. return what you say you are returning (or an immutable subclass of it).

Following these rules should reduce surprises, and that is what the code for `responseObjectForResponse` does.

You are correct, this is *defensive programming*. However; due to the prevalence of type information loss, something fundamental to this style of programming, and the issues unexpected mutability can cause; it is not *highly defensive programming*.

As Monty Python, and others, would advise: always expect the unexpected and defend against it.
HTH

Comment: There is one further thing to consider: immutable is always to be preferred over mutable, that allows better control over the object.

Comment: As an aside, one might note that MutableArray is a subclass of NSArray which is backwards from what one might expect and backward from many other APIs in other languages. Further it turns out that they are basically the same with what seems to be equivalent of an immutable bit being set.